# Are maximum-density fixed polyomino packings always isohedral?

Tags: geometry, tiling, packing-problem, polyomino

Consider, for a polyomino $P$ made from $n$ unit squares joined at the edges, the arrangements of non-overlapping translations of $P$. Sometimes we can cover the infinite plane with such translations without any gaps:

[image]

Other times, we can't, such as with the $T$ pentomino:

[image]

When we can't do this, one can ask about the maximum density attainable, hereafter $\Delta(P)$; by a compactness argument, this will always be less than $1$ if $P$ does not tile the plane.

Many times, we can get the maximum packing density by adding $k$ squares to $P$ to produce an $n+k$-omino $Q$ which *does* tile the plane by translation, which gives us $\Delta(P) \ge \frac{n}{n+k}$. For instance, with the $T$ pentomino above and $k=1$:

[image]

By a 1984 [result](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0019995884800078) of Wijshoff and van Leeuwen, any $Q$ which tiles the plane via translation can do so in an *isohedral* manner, meaning that the symmetries of the plane are transitive on the tiles. This implies the same for the arrangements of $P\subseteq Q$ as well.

I am curious whether the above result generalizes to packing densities less than one, i.e. that maximal packings of $P$ are always possible to do by placing copies of $P$ in a lattice configuration. This is equivalent to the statement that the maximal density is equal to $\frac n{n+k}$, where $k$ is the smallest number of unit squares needed to add to $P$ to form a translationally-tiling polyomino.

I've verified manually that this is the case for all polyominoes with $6$ or fewer cells, but it's not clear to me how to proceed from here. Possibly the statement I'd like to show is equivalent to the $1984$ result, but if so I don't see the proof. It's also quite possible that there are straightforward counterexamples with some larger polyominoes - in particular, any non-tiling $n$-omino that packs with density larger than $n/(n+1)$ would work. Any suggestions or pointers to relevant literature would be welcome!

Comment: A question about the rules. Judging from your comment about the T-pentomino, you apparently don't allow rotated versions? Translations only?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Yep - that's what I mean by "fixed polyomino". There are counterexamples in the heptominoes when we allow rotation.